# Is it possible to route directly to a blazor page hosted in an MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-server-side

I have an existing .net core 3.1 MVC application that I've started adding Blazor components to. This is working great, the components render and work as expected. Currently to get to a page that uses Blazor I am adding a controller action and view which handles the routing then I add the component tag to the view to render the Blazor component.

So let's say I have a Customers Blazor component, which is really a customers "page", I do the following.

1. Add a controller and action, in this example I would add a "Customers" controller with an "Index" action
2. I add the corresponding Index view
3. Create a Customers Blazor component in the Pages folder of my app
4. In the view I use the component tag helper to load the Blazor component:
   `<component type="typeof(MyApp.Pages.Customers)" render-mode="Server" />`

Like I said, all of this works just fine it's just a lot of overhead for every page I add that uses Blazor. It would be nice to be able to just use the built-in Blazor routing for pages. If this worked I could just add the Customers Blazor component in the Pages folder and add the @page tag like this:
`@page "/Customers"`

Unfortunately this does not work, I get a 404 if I try to use this method.

I have followed the instructions in this article but still receive a 404:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integrate-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-routable-components-in-an-mvc-app

Has anyone got this working? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start to finish with a fresh `dotnet new mvc` application, this is how you can do this in `.NET 5.0` ...

1. Inside of `ConfigureServices`, add:

   - `services.AddRazorPages();`
   - `services.AddServerSideBlazor();`
2. Inside of `Configure` underneath `UseEndpoints`, add:

   - `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");`
   - `endpoints.MapBlazorHub()`
3. Inside of your main layout, add the blazor server js

   - `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`
4. Using an `_Imports.razor` file, reference: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web`

   - This is a framework class library so no NuGet package needed
   - Make sure its in scope of your Blazor components!
5. Add a `_Host.cshtml` file (pull it from a Blazor app)

   - This should reference the MVC _Layout file and be blank other than the App component
   - The page route should be a unique route (just like a SPA calling to an API would be)

     ```
     // _Host.cshtml
     @page "/blazor" 
     @namespace BlazorTechTalk.MvcWithBlazorUI.Pages
     @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
     @{
          Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
     }

     <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
     ```
6. Add an `App.razor` component (from a Blazor app)
7. Add an `MainLayout` component (from a Blazor app)

   - This should be blank besides:

     ```
     @inherits LayoutComponentBase
     @Body
     ```
8. Phew, you're done, you can now add `BlazorPage.razor` pages *and components* inside your MVC project!

```
@page "/blazorpage"

<h3>BlazorPage</h3>
```

***Just in case anyone stumbles upon this and only needs Blazor components***

Do step 1-4 but you can omit:

- `services.AddRazorPages();`
- `endpoints.MapToFallbackFile("/Host");`

Comment: Great answer - I can confirm the same steps also work as-is for .NET 6.

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }.